Class extends \ArrayIterator, how to typehint the object coming out from itereting on it?
I have a class extending \ArrayIterator
class ProductDtoCollection extends \ArrayIterator
{
}

when iterating on it it will return an ProductDto object. How to let both PHPStan and VScode Intelephense know this?
I tried many things following this phpstan blog post but none of them work for VScode Intelephense.
The only things that works is to repeating every method of \ArrayIterator, but this is a hell of useless verbosity:
    /**
     * @return ProductDto
     */
    public function current(): mixed
    {
        return parent::current();
    }

or to do nearly the same with this other solution
/**
 * @method ProductDto current()
 */
class ProductDtoCollection extends \ArrayIterator
{
}

I am quite sure that there is a better and simpler way!
